# About MS COCO dataset Evaluation! Image Size! (question about COCO dataset.)

Tags: object-detection, object-detection-api, mscoco, coco

I am a student currently studying object detection!

I have a question about COCO dataset.

I'm currently experimenting with COCO datasets, and there's APs APm APL in the performance evaluation metrics.

32X32 or less for APs, 32x32 to 96×96 for APm, 96×96 for APLs
It looks like this.

Is this standard for a specific image size?
Or does it mean the absolute pixel size?
If it means absolute pixel size, will the instances included in APs APm APL be different for each input size?

Thank you.